# error: builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
test_yourself = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

#calculate the mean

mean = sum(test_yourself)/len(test_yourself)

#calculate the median of list

median = test_yourself[(len[test_yourself] + 1) / 2]
```

I am getting the error

> builtin_function_or_method object is not subscriptable.

Any help will be appreciated.
I am new to python, sorry if it is an embarrassing mistake.

Comment: `len` is a function, so you need to use parentheses and not square brackets: `test_yourself[(len(test_yourself)+ 1) / 2]`

Comment: thanks for the reply. now it is showing me error: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Answer (score 0):

Regular division results in float, you need integer foe list index.

change bracket to parenthesis and use integer division:

```
median = test_yourself[len(test_yourself) // 2]
```

or coerce to int:

```
median = test_yourself[int(len(test_yourself) / 2)]
```